# Hiding a row through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a row which I want to be hidden through javascript.
the issue is it is giving me Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required.
Row on aspx:

```
<tr id="RowCliamMessage">
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"
            Text="While .....">
        </asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
function CompareDateRange(sender,args)
{
    if ((CheckDate >= RangeDate1))
    {
        args.IsValid = true;

        if (CheckDate <= RangeDate3)
        {
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_RowCliamMessage').style.display="none";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how you get the `ContentPlaceHolder1_RowCliamMessage` ? maybe you won to type `<%=RowCliamMessage.ClientID%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You do like this dont take contentplaceholder ID**

**You can hide your TR by below code.**

```
document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

**You can visible your TR by below code.**

```
document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage').style.visibility = "visible"
```

**difference between display: none and visibility: hidden**

> visibility: hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.
>
> display: none removes the element completely from the document.
>       It does not take up any space, 
>       even though the HTML for it is still in the source code.*

Comment: thanks now I am gettign the object but ---on display="block" ---I still am unable to show the hidden row..why so??

Comment: my row has false defined for its visible property.all i want is to now make it visible through this js..what should I write?

Comment: document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage').style.visibility = "visible";

Comment: It is same as written above..just that..style.display has been replaced by what you told..when I am debugging..it is successfully coming an dpassing through the statement (visiblity="visible"

Comment: yes..the problem was that i had made the label's property false..because of which row was getting visible but I could not see the label..now I have done:  <tr id="RowCliamMessage" style="display:none" runat="server">  and in JS  document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage').style.display = "block";     Now working fine..thanks for all the help!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage'));
document.getElementById('RowCliamMessage').style.display = 'none';​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bXn6n/) on jdFiddle